# how to create a nested array and store it in database?

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a data like

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>title 1</th>
     <td>para1</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>title 2</th>
     <td>para1</td>
     <td>para2</td>
     <td>para3</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>title 3</th>
     <td>para1</td>
     <td>para2</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

now how can i take this data and make into an array..it will be really helpful if i can get a solution for this.

In my problem i have a table as shown above and want to store the data in a nested/ multidimensional array. All the solution above doesnot answer my question

thanks in advance

Comment: use javascript and ajax technologies to gather all the needed data and send it to server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect html pages to mysql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012335/how-to-connect-html-pages-to-mysql-database)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying a nested array in an HTML table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008113/displaying-a-nested-array-in-an-html-table)

Comment: And just like that duplicate question, this kind of question is really too broad to answer on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to convert html table to php array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553897/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-html-table-to-php-array)

Comment: i was going to close it as a dupe of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php but maybe the OP will come back and add a few details

Comment: @KyleWilliamson i am trying to do exactly the opposite of what is been done in that post..so can you help me out with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you are looking for...  It's actually pretty simple.

You want to iterate through the `<table>` tags first .. And subsequently iterate the children `tr - td`s.

I'd surround the `table`s with a surrounding `div` to make grabbing them much easier.

Then I'd use jQuery because the library makes it easy to choose children etc etc.  Then for Storage into the database .. I'd "Json-ify" the array(s)

IE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  myHTML = $('#myDiv').html();
});

var tableNumber = $('#myDiv').children('table').length;

var items = [];

for (i = 0; i < tableNumber; i++) {
  var title = $($("table tr th")[i]).html();

  var paras = [];

  $($("table tr")[i]).find('td').each(function() {
    paras.push($(this).html());
  });
  items.push(title, paras);
}

var outPut = JSON.stringify(items);

$('#jsonOut').html(outPut);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>title 1</th>
      <td>para 1-1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>title 2</th>
      <td>para 2-1</td>
      <td>para 2-2</td>
      <td>para 2-3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>title 3</th>
      <td>para 3-1</td>
      <td>para 3-2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br>
<pre>
 <div id="jsonOut">
 
 </div> 
</pre>
```

You can also view the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zf6a5t9g/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am trying to parse that html in php

Comment: You're not being clear.. What EXACTLY are you doing?  From beginning to end.  Are you receiving that HTML from a database?  Are you trying to do what I just did, but in PHP?  Give us a 30,000 foot view of the process from beginning to end..